# Find the nearest future or equal to date from a table of dates with sql stmt

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

Table 1

```
ID | T1_Date
---+-------------
 1 | 09/08/2020
 2 | 09/30/2020
```

Table 2

```
T2_Date    | Label
-----------+-----
08/31/2020 | Aug-20
09/20/2020 | Sep-20
10/25/2020 | Oct-20
```

I'm trying to have the result link the nearest future date label from table 2 with each record in table 1.  So my output would look like:

```
ID | T1_Date    | Label
---+------------+--------
 1 | 09/08/2020 | Sep-20
 2 | 09/30/2020 | Oct-20
```

So far I can only return all the records that are greater than the `T1_Date` value, so it repeats all the labels.

Is there a way to just grab the nearest future date label or the equal to label?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are currently using? Having a basis would be very useful for helping you as we might be able to just quickly fix your code then making our own.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks marc_s.  will do in future posts.  thanks for cleaning up this one!

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(t2.label) keep (dense_rank first t2.date asc)
        from t2
        where t2.date > t1.date
       ) 
from t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways, you can solve this problem

```
    One way which is pretty simple but not optimal:
    
   select 
    t1.*
    ,(select Label from table2 where t2_date=(select MIN(T2_Date)from table2 
     where T2_Date>=T1_Date))Label
    from table1 t1
-----------------------------------------------------------    
    The second Way: 
    
    with TempTable as 
    (
    select T1_Date,min(T2_Date)T2_Date 
    from table2
    left join table1 on T2_Date>=T1_Date
    group by T1_Date
    )
    select t1.T1_Date,t2.Label from TempTable temp 
    left join table1 t1 on t1.T1_Date=temp.T1_Date
    left join table2 t2 on t2.T2_Date=temp.T2_Date
```